# Fullcalendar events displayed twice using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, fullcalendar

I have integrated fullcalendar with codeigniter framework. Pulling events from my MySQL database works fine, as does rescheduling events using eventDrop. My issue is that all events are displayed twice in my calendar. Moreover, the dates in the calendar are shifted to match the duration of the first instance of the event. How can I get rid of the second display? I suspect that it has something to do with the css, or the codeigniter framework, but I can't pinpoint where or how.

I have ruled out issues related with the database. Even if I add events as an array like I have done in the example below,  I see this issue.

**Problem description:**
An empty calendar is displayed correctly with each date aligned in the top right corner. If I add an event like the one in the code below, I see two events. The first one is displayed correctly on the defined date(s), but immediately after I see a second instance of the same event. In addition, the grid dates are now shifted to the left and are no longer aligned with the table grid. If I, for example extend the event to last for a whole week (like in the code below) the Sunday date is displayed in the center of the table grid, followed by the second instance of the event.

If I reschedule, I need to select the first event, but the second one moves around.

I see this error message when I reschedule:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'el' of undefined   fullcalendar.js:3338

I have not been able to get eventResize to work.

**Codeigniter set-up**
I have put the fullcalendar files in the asset/fullcalendar folder and add them using a helper function like so:

```
function asset_url(){
   return base_url().'assets/';
}

/* End of file utility_helper.php */
/* Location: ./application/helpers/utility_helper.php */
```

**Here is my header view:**

```
<?php echo doctype("html5"); ?>
<head>
<?php echo meta('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'equiv');?>
<!-- Full calendar stylesheets -->
<?php echo link_tag('assets/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css'); ?>
<?php echo link_tag('assets/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.print.css','stylesheet','text/css','','print'); ?>
<!-- fullcalendar js-files -->
<script src='<?php echo asset_url();?>fullcalendar/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='<?php echo asset_url();?>fullcalendar/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='<?php echo asset_url();?>fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
     allDayDefault: false,
     editable : true,
     resizeable : true,
     events: [
      {
          title  : 'event1',
          start  : '2015-03-01',
          end    : '2015-03-08'
      },
     ],
    });
   });
 </script>
 </head>
```

**Here is my body view:**

```
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

**EDIT:**

**Populating the calendar from/to db**

When populating the calendar from MySQL, I replace the "events:" in the header with the following code:

```
events: "<?php echo site_url().'/project/show_events';?>",
```

**Controller function**

```
function show_events() {

    //populate the calendar from db
    $this->load->model('calendar');
    $data['json'] = $this->calendar->getCalendar();
    $this->load->view('calendar', $data);
}
```

**Model calendar.php**

```
<?php
Class Calendar extends CI_Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function getCalendar()
    {
        $sql = "SELECT PROJ_PRODUCTIONORDER.id as id, CONCAT(PROJ_PRODUCTIONORDER.ordernumber, ' ', PROJ_CLIENTLIST.clientname) as title, PROJ_PRODUCTIONORDER.start as start, PROJ_PRODUCTIONORDER.end as endd
                FROM PROJ_PRODUCTIONORDER, PROJ_CLIENTLIST
                WHERE PROJ_PRODUCTIONORDER.clientid=PROJ_CLIENTLIST.id
                ORDER BY PROJ_PRODUCTIONORDER.id";

        $result = $this->db->query($sql);

        return $result;
    }
```

**View calendar.php**

```
<?php
$jsonevents = array();

foreach($json->result() as $entry)
{
$jsonevents[] = array(
    'id' => $entry->id,
    'title' => $entry->title,
    'start' => $entry->start,
    'end' => $entry->endd,
    'allDay' => '',
    );

}

 echo json_encode($jsonevents);
```

The calendar.php echoes the following array of events:

```
[{"id":"1","title":"ordernumber1 clientname1","start":"2015-03-01","end":"2015-03-08","allDay":""},{"id":"2","title":"ordernumber2 clientname2","start":"2015-04-01","end":"2014-04-03","allDay":""}]
```

Any help regarding this issue will be most appreciated.

Comment: How are you passing events to calendar ? share the array. There is no problem with you code above. The problem has to be the array you are passing off to the calendar.

Comment: Hi, I've added the code on how the events are passed to the calendar. The displayed result is the same as in my original post. Unfortunately.

Comment: try `allDay=true` and also show how are you passing these events in the calendar. Are you using `eventsources` or passing it directly

Comment: Solved. I found that the calendar table was generating some extra <td> after en event which is why all events were displaced to the left. Anyway, I moved the calendar into it's own controller and now it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I found that the calendar table was generating some extra  after en event which is why all events were displaced to the left. Anyway, I moved the calendar into it's own controller and now it works like a charm.